# RCSB PDB - how to choose between multiple copies of the same protein?

Tags: crystal-structure, molecular-structure, proteins

I want to map the location of missense mutations on a protein, `SERPINB3`. I intend to do this using [PyMol](https://www.pymol.org/) and download the protein structure from [RCSB PDB](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do). However, searching for `SERPINB3` reveals two molecular structures (as well as one homolog, `SERPINB4`).

One of the structures, `2zv6`, presents the protein as a multimer of three identical chains. This structure is older (2009) and is used by computational tools on CbioPortal.

Another structure, `4zk3`, presents the protein as monomer and has been more recently published (2015).

I am inclined to trust the more recent protein over the older one on the vague notions that:

1. Its newer so it was probably an improvement in terms of some aspect of the structural determination process
2. I've heard that its "unusual" for a multimer to form with three identical chains

...which are not particularly good rationalizations.

I have not found any literature comparing these competing molecular structures and honestly I am not entirely clear on how different they are from each other beyond the fact that one is presented as a multimer.

**What justifications can be made based on chemistry and/or biology to support one of these structures over the other?** I am interested in both choosing between these two structures and in general good practices for choosing between two competing structures.

Comment: Did you checked if monomer in first case differs from second deposit?

Comment: Yes, there are differences in the number of a-helices and B-sheets

Comment: 2zv6 and 4zk3 are, upon inspection, completely different proteins. I'm afraid you made strange mistake thinking them describing the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean they are completely different proteins? Both turn up in a search for "SerpinB3", both are referenced to the same Uniprot ID (P29508), running a BLASTp search comparing one subunit of 2zv6 to 4zk3 returns an Score of 1640 and E-value of 0 indicating high degree of sequence similarity with an infinitesimally low chance of the similarity being due to random chance.

Comment: They are coded by the same gene but are different. Even length is different!